# Cannot Rotate camera in 3D view

Tags: camera

I'm currently having a problem with the 3D view -while working on a model, I suddenly wasn't able to rotate my camera anymore. I can manipulate the model just fine, the camera is the problem. I checked the Manipulate Center Points, Lock camera and pretty much everything I could find -I even reinstalled Blender! Still stuck, regretably. My mouse works fine, it zooms in and out perfectly. I just can't seem to rotate around the mesh. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Does this happen in only one file, or in any file? Maybe related post - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52412/i-cannot-rotate-of-move-camera-anymore-for-some-reason?rq=1

Comment: Please add more info to your question like scene screenshots, settings, or possibly upload your blendfile

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but have you tried pressing <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (period) it sometimes can reset the view (best way I can explain it) or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> if that doesn't work.

[More info](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19320/cant-move-in-the-3d-view-with-mouse)

Answer (score 2):

In the 3D view header, find the icon that lets you change your pivot point.  Just to the right of that icon you will see an icon with three dots along the top and a left and right pointing double arrow below.  Clicking on that icon toggles rotation.  It's easy to click on it by accident.

Comment: I've tried with that icon, unfortunately that's no the cause. This is happening to all of my files, even new, unsaved ones when I reinstalled Blender. Using the Emulate 3 Button Mouse works, which is strange because zooming with the wheel works fine. It's just rotating that doesn't work anymore -resetting the user preferences hasn't fixed it.

Comment: Just changed mouse, reinstalled blender again, still no fix. This is getting bothersome :/

Comment: Thank you. It solved my trouble with the camera. I've duplicated it from another camera with transform locks enabled, and after disabling the locks, it stopped to rotate. I thought it's somehow about locks, but it turned as it's about my curly hands! :-)